# copy one vector to another, omitting NA values

Tags: r

How can I selectively over-write the old vector? I want to add in the replacement values, but only where they are not = `NA`.

So starting with this data:

```
old.vector <- 1:5
replacement.values <- c('x', 'y', NA, 'z', NA)
```

I want to end up with this vector:
new.vector: `c('x', 'y', 3, 'z', 5)`

edit: Thanks for the welcome and help. It's great to see a bunch of different ways of doing the same thing.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is basic vector operation in `R`, try google it. Queries like "r vector subset" might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this, also:

```
old.vector<-ifelse(is.na(replacement.values),old.vector,replacement.values)
```

And `old.vector` then looks like

```
old.vector
[1] "x" "y" "3" "z" "5"
```

If the vectors are of *compatible* length.

Comment: Since the OPs question is a direct description of what `ifelse` does, I provided that as an answer, as the OP is unaware that such a function exists. I provided a faster method of achieving the same results in my comment correcting your answer. If the OP wants the fastest method, then they should go with @lukeA's method.

Answer (score 3):

Another similar to Lukes way would be just simple replacement by indx

```
indx <- is.na(replacement.values)
replacement.values[indx] <- old.vector[indx]
## [1] "x" "y" "3" "z" "5"
```

Or you can do it the other way around (as suggested by @RusanKax)

```
indx <- !is.na(replacement.values)
old.vector[indx] <- replacement.values[indx]
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, this does not *overwrite* `old.vector`, as the OP specified. Although this does: `indx<-!is.na(replacement.values); old.vector[indx]<-replacement.values[indx]`

Comment: You, can do it that way too, though I don't think it matters too much which vector to override.

Answer (score 2):

```
idx <- is.na(replacement.values)
replace(replacement.values, idx, old.vector[idx])
# [1] "x" "y" "3" "z" "5"
```